# I have a c++ library file which is using In my qt project. Which is a . so file(shared object)

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, android-library, shared-objects

When I try add the c++ library file. so (shared object ) which can't be loaded in android.

I need to add the same in my android studio project.
. so file is having its header file because it used in Qt. When I created the same project in android I need to use the same library but it is created in c++ and it is. So file.

Can I add it as the same or how can I covert the same to android supported form.

Comment: Where did you get this `.so` file? Make sure it was compiled for android and not some other OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this library in Android you need to compile it using Android NDK. Then link this library in your target in CMake. Android will put all symbols you use from .so to your target during compilation.